# Mounted Docker volume has different ownership when using Travis

Tags: docker, travis-ci

This question relates to [this repository](https://github.com/warwickdatasciencesociety/research-website) with the most relevant Travis job [here](https://travis-ci.com/github/warwickdatasciencesociety/research-website/jobs/457541113).

The repository is for static site built from Jupyter notebooks. The notebooks are converted using `build/build.py` which, for each post, builds a Docker image, starts a corresponding container with the post notebook directory mounted, and uses `nbconvert` to convert the notebook to Markdown. One step of `nbconvert`'s conversion involves creating a supporting file directory. This fails on Travis due to a permission issue.

In attempting to debug this problem, I found that the ownership and permissions of the repo are the same on my local machine and Travis (with my username switched for `travis`) before running Docker. Despite this, inside the mounted volume of the Docker container, the ownerships are different:

Local:

```
drwxrwxr-x 3 jovyan  1000   4096 Dec 10 19:56 .
drwsrwsr-x 1 jovyan users   4096 Dec  3 21:51 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jovyan  1000    105 Dec  7 09:57 Dockerfile
drwxr-xr-x 2 jovyan  1000   4096 Dec 10 12:09 .ipynb_checkpoints
-rw-r--r-- 1 jovyan  1000 154229 Dec 10 12:28 post.ipynb
```

Travis:

```
drwxrwxr-x 2   2000  2000  4096 Dec 10 19:58 .
drwsrwsr-x 1 jovyan users  4096 Nov  8 16:37 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1   2000  2000   101 Dec 10 19:58 Dockerfile
-rw-rw-r-- 1   2000  2000 35271 Dec 10 19:58 post.ipynb
```

Both my local machine and Travis are running Ubuntu 20.04, have the same version of Docker, and all other tools come from Conda so should behave the same. I am struggling to understand where this difference in ownership is coming from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running the docker again with this command, so the uid outside the container is propagated inside:

```
docker run -u `id -u`
```

*alternative, as pointed by **@anemyte**:*

```
docker run -u $(id -u)
```

---

This should involve the creation of the new files inside the docker to be owned by `"jovyan"`.

If you are able to guess that mounting points will exist, you could also pre-create them so the ownership of the files inside is also correct:

```
docker run -v /path/on/host:/path/in/container ...
```

If you set the permissions of your local path `(/path/on/host)` as `777`, that will also be propagated to the mounting point: no permission error will be thrown regardless of the user that docker uses to create those files.

After that, you'll be free to restore permissions, if needed.

Comment: I'm curious why do you use the back-tics (\`id -u\`) instead of `$(id -u)`? This notation as a debugging nightmare.

Comment: @anemyte I just learnt it that way, no real reason to be sincere. I agree with your comment. It's just cleaner and avoids `where_is_the_tick_in_my_keyboard` errors.